# Identify the actual TAT(Turn Around Time) by comparing two date columns

Tags: sql, oracle, date, overlapping

I am having a table with the following structure, using which I am trying to find the TAT(Turn Around Time) between two days. But, do the overlapping days, I am unable to find the actual TAT

```
Appln No        Start Date  End Date
1001009     01-10-15    06-10-15
1001009     02-10-15    04-10-15
1001009     03-10-15    04-10-15
1001009     03-10-15    05-10-15
1001009     04-10-15    07-10-15
1001009     09-10-15    10-10-15
1001009     12-10-15    16-10-15
1001009     14-10-15    17-10-15
```

After removing the overlapping dates from the above sample data, the output will be in the following format -

```
Appln No    Start Date  End Date
1001009     01-10-15    07-10-15
1001009     09-10-15    10-10-15
1001009     12-10-15    17-10-15
```

Since I am a beginner in sql and using oracle sql developer, I am finding it difficult to write the above logic into code. Any suggestion on the issue is welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t1.* from myTable t1
inner join myTable t2
on t2.StartDate > t1.StartDate and t2.StartDate < t1.EndDate
```

Comment: Won't work if there's only one record for an "Appln".

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky query.  You need to identify groups that overlap, by assigning a grouping id.  One way to do this is to find where the overlapping groups start, then accumulate the number of starts between each record.

The following assumes that your table has a primary key (called `id` for lack of a better name).

This gives the opportunity to aggregate to get what you want:

```
select ApplnNo, min(start), max(end)
from (select t.*,
             sum(IsGroupStart) over (partition by ApplnNo order by start) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when exists (select 1
                                      from t t2
                                      where t2.end >= t.start and t2.start <= t.end and
                                            t2.id <> t.id
                                     )
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as IsGroupStart
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by ApplnNo, grp;
```

There are some nuances.  The exact innermost subquery for `exists` depends on how you define overlaps.  This includes even one day of overlap at the beginning or end.

Comment: Nice and elegant approach using *SUM* instead of *LAST_VALUE*. But I assume the condition in the subqeury should be `where t2.end >  t.start and t2.start  <  t.start` instead of `where t2.end >= t.start and t2.start  <= t.end`. 1) Only start day is used to test overlap, i.e. only the left side is considered. 2) At least one of the conditions should be *less than*. Otherwise subquery returns **always** records.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber . . . Actually, changing the inequalities doesn't work.  The table needs a primary key to prevent counting the same record.  Really good catch.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I was close to filling SR as of *unexpected behaviour* :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this after I am back at my office.

Answer (score 1):

More that a tricky task, as you can't trust any order of the intervals.
I attack it by removing the subintervals (intervals completely covered in other interval).
After this I can follow the order defined by START_DATE to see if the perceeding interval is overlaping with the next one and apply the standard grouping mechanism.

```
 with subs as (
 /* first remove all intervals that are subsets of other intervals */
 select * from tst t1
 where NOT exists (select null from tst t2 where t2.start_date < t1.start_date and t1.end_date < t2.end_date)
 ),overlap as (
 select APPLN_NO, START_DATE, END_DATE,
 case when (nvl(lag(END_DATE) over (partition by APPLN_NO order by START_DATE),START_DATE-1)  < START_DATE) then 
      row_number() over (partition by APPLN_NO order by START_DATE) end grp
 from subs),
 overlap2 as (
 select 
 APPLN_NO, START_DATE, END_DATE, GRP,
 last_value(grp ignore nulls) over (partition by APPLN_NO order by START_DATE) as grp2
 from overlap)
 select 
   APPLN_NO,   min(START_DATE) START_DATE, max(END_DATE) END_DATE
 from overlap2
 group by APPLN_NO, grp2
 order by 1,2
 ;
```

For checking the query here my setup

```
 drop table tst ;
 create table tst 
 (appln_no number,
 start_date date,
 end_date date);

 insert into tst values (1001009, to_date('01-10-15','dd-mm-rr'),to_date('06-10-15','dd-mm-rr'));
 insert into tst values (1001009, to_date('02-10-15','dd-mm-rr'),to_date('04-10-15','dd-mm-rr'));
 insert into tst values (1001009, to_date('03-10-15','dd-mm-rr'),to_date('04-10-15','dd-mm-rr'));
 insert into tst values (1001009, to_date('03-10-15','dd-mm-rr'),to_date('05-10-15','dd-mm-rr'));
 insert into tst values (1001009, to_date('04-10-15','dd-mm-rr'),to_date('07-10-15','dd-mm-rr'));
 insert into tst values (1001009, to_date('09-10-15','dd-mm-rr'),to_date('10-10-15','dd-mm-rr'));
 insert into tst values (1001009, to_date('12-10-15','dd-mm-rr'),to_date('16-10-15','dd-mm-rr'));
 insert into tst values (1001009, to_date('13-10-15','dd-mm-rr'),to_date('14-10-15','dd-mm-rr')); /* this is added to make it more interesting */
 insert into tst values (1001009, to_date('15-10-15','dd-mm-rr'),to_date('17-10-15','dd-mm-rr'));
```

give

```
    APPLN_NO START_DATE          END_DATE          
 ---------- ------------------- -------------------
    1001009 01.10.2015 00:00:00 07.10.2015 00:00:00 
    1001009 09.10.2015 00:00:00 10.10.2015 00:00:00 
    1001009 12.10.2015 00:00:00 17.10.2015 00:00:00
```

as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this after I am back at my office. I have one doubt though. This query will work in oracle sql developer, right? I have not used 'with subs as' in any of my oracle queries so far.

Comment: @Mathew don't wory [subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2129904) works in Sql Developer like a charm.